# Change Eclipse's search occurrences highlighting (Search tab)

Tags: eclipse, color-scheme

How can I change the occurences highlighting in the Search tab of Eclipse? I've managed to change the Annotations colors under (General>Editors>Text Editors>Annotations) which works for the editor but not for the Search tab.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Appearance` -> `Color and Fonts`. Expand `Basic` -> `Match highlight background color`.

Comment: Eclipse maze of preferences and colors, sigh

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it stays the same highlight?